# Loading stringWithContentsofURL that requires credentials

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, authentication, nsdata

I am trying to parse an HTML page, but the page requires a username/password to access the data.
How do I pass the credentials to the server so I can load the webpage into my NSData object?

*UPDATE for Comments Below*

Normally if you are using a web browser, it will pop up a login window for you to type in the credentials. When I execute it in iOS, it doesn't give me anything.

Thanks a lot!
Alan

Comment: Are you trying to get data from the page?

Comment: Is there a log in area on the site, or does a window come up asking for credentials?

Comment: Don't use stringWithContentsOfURL...it can't handle that kind of info and it will block your thread will it waits for data.  Use NSURLConnection or ASIHTTPRequest to work with net connections.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get data from the page. A window pops up for creds. I will look into ASIHTTPRequest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASIFormDataRequest`. Take a look at it [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

```
    NSURL *tempUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoursitetoparse.com"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] init];

    request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:tempUrl];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setUsername:@"username"]; //Username
    [request setPassword:@"password"]; //Password

    [request startAsynchronous];
```

And it's delegate methods:

```
-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    NSLog(@"Failed %@ with code %d and with userInfo %@",[error domain],[error code],[error userInfo]);


}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request


{

    NSLog(@"Finished : %@",[theRequest responseString]);     

}
```